# python regex with a variable not working when it contains specific characters

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm working with a dataframe with some medicines and I want extract the dosage from a full sentence taken from the product description. There's a dosage for every Active Substance (DCI), which are fed in a list. The dosage for every DCI is generally after its name in the `description`.

I'm using:

```
teste=[]
for x in listofdci:
   teste2 = [f"{x}{y}" for x,y in re.findall(rf"(?:{x})\s*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)\s*(g|mg|)",strength)]
   teste.extend(teste2)
```

It works well except for cases where the variable contains `()` or `+`, for example:

```
listofdci = [' Acid. L(+)-lacticum D4']
description = ' Acid. L(+)-lacticum D4 250 mg'
#error: nothing to repeat

#

listofdci = ['Zinkoxid', '(+/–)-α-Bisabolol', 'Lebertran (Typ A)', 'Retinol (Vitamin A)', 'Colecalciferol (Vitamin D3)']
description = 'Zinkoxid 13 g, (+/–)-α-Bisabolol 0,026 g (eingesetzt als Dragosantol-Zubereitung), Lebertran (Typ A) 5,2 g, Retinol (Vitamin A) 24,5 mg (entspr. 41 600 I.E. Retinolpalmitat [enth. Butylhydroxyanisol, Butylhydroxytoluol]), Colecalciferol (Vitamin D3) 10,4 mg (entspr. 10 400 I.E. mittelkettige Triglyceride [enth. all-rac-α-Tocopherol])'
#error: nothing to repeat
#Here he collects the first dosage -> ['13g'] and then outputs the error

#

listofdci = [' Efeublätter-Trockenextrakt']
description = ' Efeublätter-Trockenextrakt (5-7,5:1) 65 mg - Auszugsmittel: Ethanol 30% (m/m)'
#[]
#here it outputs an empty list
```

Ideally I want to have:

```
listofdci = [' Acid. L(+)-lacticum D4']
description = ' Acid. L(+)-lacticum D4 250 mg'
#['250mg']

#

listofdci = ['Zinkoxid', '(+/–)-α-Bisabolol', 'Lebertran (Typ A)', 'Retinol (Vitamin A)', 'Colecalciferol (Vitamin D3)']
description = 'Zinkoxid 13 g, (+/–)-α-Bisabolol 0,026 g (eingesetzt als Dragosantol-Zubereitung), Lebertran (Typ A) 5,2 g, Retinol (Vitamin A) 24,5 mg (entspr. 41 600 I.E. Retinolpalmitat [enth. Butylhydroxyanisol, Butylhydroxytoluol]), Colecalciferol (Vitamin D3) 10,4 mg (entspr. 10 400 I.E. mittelkettige Triglyceride [enth. all-rac-α-Tocopherol])'
#['13g','0,026','5,2g','24,5','10,4']

#

listofdci = [' Efeublätter-Trockenextrakt']
description = ' Efeublätter-Trockenextrakt (5-7,5:1) 65 mg - Auszugsmittel: Ethanol 30% (m/m)'
#[65mg]
```

I don't know how to dodge this specific problem, besides maybe removing every `()` or `+` from the dataset. Also, because those characters can appear in every part of the string I don't think I can identify them using sets: '[]'

Comment: You probably need to use [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to make sure the special characters are not interpreted as regex directives. `(` and `+` have special meaning in regular expressions. 

`re.findall(rf"(?:{re.escape(x)})\s*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)\s*(g|mg|)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there can be an optional substring inside parentheses between the keyword and number, you can use

```py
teste=[]
for x in listofdci:
    test2 = [f"{x}{y}" for x,y in re.findall(rf"{re.escape(x)}(?:\s*\([^()]*\))?\s*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)\s*(m?g\b|)", description)]
    if test2:
        teste.extend(test2)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/E78Czj).

*Details*:

- `{re.escape(x)}` - the escaped keyword
- `(?:\s*\([^()]*\))?` - an optional sequence of zero or more whitespaces, `(`, zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)` - one or more digtis, and then zero or more sequences of `.` / `,` and one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(m?g\b|)` - `m`, `mg` as whole words, or empty string.